# Fill blank spaces VBA

Tags: excel, vba, fill

I want to fill the blank spaces in a table, where in some months there are debts that doesnt have information and i have defined the data set by the name "Base1", but when i tried to run it it show  ERROR 13. The data has a range B10:H32

Sub FiltroCh()

```
If Range("Base1") = 48 Then

ActiveSheet.Range("$C$11:$I$58").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("-", _
    "1", "="), Operator:=xlFilterValues

Else

ActiveSheet.Range("$B$10:$H$32").AutoFilter Field:=1

End If
```

End Sub

Comment: What is the `48` all about? With what value do you want to fill the filtered cells? What is the connection between `"$C$11:$I$58"` and `"$B$10:$H$32"`? Sharing a screenshot of your worksheet would help a lot.

Comment: 48 its the lenght of the data set, i have another sheet where it works, "$B$10:$H$32" should be "$C$11:$I$58"